# Specifying axis order by another column with ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
df_ex <- read.table("df_example.txt", header=TRUE, sep=" ")
```

where df_example.txt has the contents of:

```
name_age age distance
Stu_27 27 6.28
Stu_27 27 5.66
Stu_27 27 5.25
Ben_22 22 3.85
Ben_22 22 4.01
Ben_22 22 4.22
Liz_40 40 3.99
Liz_40 40 4.21
Liz_40 40 4.65
```

then

```
ggplot(df_ex, aes(x = distance, y = name_age)) + geom_density_ridges(scale = 1.5, fill="lightblue", rel_min_height=0.00001)
```

produces a plot as follows
[image]

**How can I order the y-axis by *age* while still showing the y-axis labels with "name_age" format? 
The order from bottom to top should be Ben_22 Stu_27 Liz_40**

I tried to apply a factor following the ggplot documentation, however when I performed the command

```
ggplot(df_ex, aes(x = distance, y = factor(name_age, levels=age))) + geom_density_ridges(scale = 1.5, fill="lightblue", rel_min_height=0.00001)
```

I received an error

```
Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = as.character(levels)) : 
  factor level [2] is duplicated
```

Comment: Not related to `ggplot2`, check the `age` vector it contains duplicated values (same problem as here `factor(1, c(1, 1))`), voting to close

Comment: Use `reorder` to order a factor by another column. Assuming it's already a factor (`df_ex$name_age = factor(df_ex$name_age)` if it's not), re-order the levels by the mean of the `age` column with `df_ex$name_age = reorder(df_ex$name_age, df_ex$age, FUN = mean)`.

Comment: Thank you @Gregor, it works well. That is indeed a solution if you wish to answer the question.

Comment: I think it's well covered in the FAQs marked as duplicates.